# SQL select where there is only one date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently this query:

```
SELECT     InvoiceNumber, CustomerCode, Amount, InvoiceDate
FROM         Invoice
```

Returns:

```
aaa, 111, 5, 07/12/2009
bbb, 111, 5, 07/11/2009
ccc, 222, 5, 07/12/2009
```

However, I want to write: `Where date = '07/12/2009'`, but I only want to return the results where there the customer has only one invoice...

So Customercode 222 would be returned, but 111 wont, as 111 has invoices from previous months....

Hope you can help! :D

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Comment: Sql server. None of the below seem to be working, but trying to figure it out

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on what the expected output is? I see 3 answers that appear to fulfil my understanding of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DateParam datetime
SELECT @DateParam = Convert(datetime, '07/12/2009', 103)

SELECT InvoiceNumber, CustomerCode, Amount, InvoiceDate
FROM Invoice
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerCode
    FROM Invoice
    GROUP BY CustomerCode
    HAVING Count(*) = 1) AS InvoiceCount ON Invoice.CustomerCode = InvoiceCount.CustomerCode
WHERE InvoiceDate = @DateParam
```

This will return any where the InvoiceDate is equal to @DateParam, and where there is only one invoice for the customer in the entire Invoice table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(10), 
        CustomerCode VARCHAR(10), 
        Amount FLOAT, 
        InvoiceDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table (InvoiceNumber,CustomerCode,Amount,InvoiceDate) SELECT 'aaa', '111', 5, '07/12/2009'
INSERT INTO @Table (InvoiceNumber,CustomerCode,Amount,InvoiceDate) SELECT 'bbb', '111', 5, '07/11/2009'
INSERT INTO @Table (InvoiceNumber,CustomerCode,Amount,InvoiceDate) SELECT 'ccc', '222', 5, '07/12/2009'

SELECT  t.*
FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  CustomerCode
            FROM    @Table
            GROUP BY CustomerCode
            HAVING COUNT(CustomerCode) = 1
        ) s ON t.CustomerCode = s.CustomerCode
WHERE   t.InvoiceDate = '07/12/2009'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  MAX(InvoiceNumber) AS InvoiceNumber
 ,CustomerCode
 ,MAX(Amount) AS Amount
 ,MAX(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceDate
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY CustomerCode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  AND MAX(InvoiceDate) = '07/12/2009'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      InvoiceNumber, CustomerCode, Amount, InvoiceDate
FROM        Invoice AS Inv
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT CustomerCode
    FROM   Invoice
    GROUP BY CustomerCode
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS base
ON        Inv.CustomerCode = base.CustomerCode
WHERE  InvoiceDate = '07/12/2009'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    i.InvoiceNumber, i.CustomerCode, i.Amount, i.InvoiceDate
FROM      Invoice i
WHERE  i.InvoiceDate = '7/12/2009'
AND    i.InvoiceNumber IN  (
   SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber)
   FROM   Invoice      
   GROUP BY CustomerCode
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: You can't put InvoiceNumber in the select list of your sub-query unless you use an aggregate. MAX(InvoiceNumber) would work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this bud

```
SELECT     InvoiceNumber, CustomerCode, Amount, InvoiceDate, (SELECT count(*) FROM Invoice b WHERE a.CustomerCode=b.CustomerCode AND InvoiceDate = '07/12/2009') as count
FROM         Invoice a
Where InvoiceDate = '07/12/2009'
HAVING count = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
SELECT
    InvoiceNumber, CustomerCode, Amount, InvoiceDate
FROM
    Invoice
WHERE
    COUNT(id) = 1 AND InvoiceDate = '07/12/2009'
GROUP BY
    InvoiceDate
```

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested, this one seems to not be accepted under SQLSERVER

```
SELECT * 
FROM Invoice i 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerCode, InvoiceDate 
  FROM Invoice 
  WHERE InvoiceDate='07/12/2009' 
  GROUP BY CustomerCode 
  HAVING COUNT(CustomerCode)=1
 ) grp ON (i.CustomerCode=grp.CustomerCode AND i.InvoiceDate=grp.InvoiceDate)
```

or if the invoice number is unique

```
SELECT * 
FROM Invoice i 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT InvoiceNumber 
  FROM Invoice 
  WHERE InvoiceDate='07/12/2009' 
  GROUP BY CustomerCode 
  HAVING COUNT(CustomerCode)=1
 ) grp ON (i.InvoiceNumber =grp.InvoiceNumber)
```

Comment: This will return customers that have multiple invoices since the WHERE clause filters the results before the GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes i have forget the date in the last one

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'Invoice.InvoiceDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks, i havent got any error in mysql, too bad it doesnt work the same for msql